# Adding UISearchBar in UINavigationBar with constraints

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, landscape-portrait

All,

I want to add UISearchBar to UINavigationbar, I dont dont want to use UISearchController, Just UISearchbar programmatically and it must work in landscape as well.

I tried it is working well in Portrait well, but in Landscape, i have issues in iPhone X  width. Can we use Constraints.

Below is the code

[image]

```
 CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    search = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width - 2 * 44 - 2 * 15, 44)];
    search.delegate = self; //    search.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    search.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    search.placeholder = @"Search";
    search.translucent = NO;
    search.opaque = NO;
    search.showsCancelButton = NO;
    [search setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

    //customize textfield inside UISearchBar
    @try {
        for (id object in [[[search subviews] firstObject] subviews])
        {
            if (object && [object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;
                textFieldObject.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                textFieldObject.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
                textFieldObject.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([brandingObj getValueForKey:navBarTitleColor]);
                textFieldObject.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error while customizing UISearchBar");
    }
    @finally {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use UISearchDisplayController, its highly configurable and recommended by apple, working with geometry (CGRecr, CGFrame, etc.) to adjust UIKit objects layout could be a pain, use auto layout avoiding UIKits convenience initializers, to adjust later constraints.

Anyway if you want explicitly do with this way, this should work.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UISearchBarDelegate>
    @property UISearchBar *searchbar;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _searchbar = [UISearchBar new];
    _searchbar.delegate = self;
    _searchbar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchbar;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Maybe you should need configure appearance , take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarmetrics?language=objc)

Cheers.